# What is that :name syntax?

Tags: typeorm

In TypeORM [documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md), there are examples like this:

```
import {getConnection} from "typeorm";

await getConnection()
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .update(User)
  .set({ firstName: "Timber", lastName: "Saw" })
  .where("id = :id", { id: 1 })
  .execute();
```

Where can I find more information on that `:id` syntax? Can it be used in the `.set` method also?

Comment: I don't know about TypeOrm, but it looks like a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a query parameter: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#using-parameters-to-escape-data

I don't think it makes sense to use it in the set-method, since you are passing an object there, which should already be escaped. Query parameters are used to make queries more readable and to prevent SQL injections.